# DialogFlow actions-on-google: state handler for Google home actions using node js

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

How to achieve "state handler advanced coding of Alexa" in actions-on-google for DialogFlow V2 coding version using node js?

Comment: hope this link helps: https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-nodejs-client-v2

Comment: The accepted answer might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47155026/dialogflow-api-ai-amazon-echo-integration-simple-plain-text-bot-for-testing

Comment: No, not the solution for the problem of state handler

Comment: https://dialogflow.com/docs/integrations/alexa-importer#replace_the_request_handler

Comment: I haven't worked with Dialogflow or Alexa. Just trying to help.